Are questions about trading on-topic?
I've noticed some trading questions that ask about topics that cannot be closed as off-topic because they are about bitcoin, but where the real question is only incidentally related to bitcoin and can be answered in general non-bitcoin terms. For example:

Questions about how to calculate profit/loss
Questions about the effect on one's assets of an increase or decrease in price
Questions about the effect of trading between crypto-currencies
Questions about trading techniques such as margin trading, shorts, etc.

I feel like I would like to close these with a reason of "this question does not fundamentally relate to bitcoin and can be explained using general concepts from other disciplines including mathematics, accountancy, financial trading, security, etc.". This is not the same as blatantly off-topic, because the questions are usually in the context of bitcoin.
So my questions are:

Are these questions currently on-topic?
Is the above reason a legitimate reason to want to close issues?
Considering questions 1 and 2, how should questions like these be handled?


funny no one has touched this one.

I think they are off topic. Because how a crypto currency trades with another currency is not related to the crypto currency technology. In fact most currencies don't even have any notion of currency exchange built into the technology. So it's really traded in any way someone wants to and implemented in non crypto technology. I'd say the ball is really in the defense of such questions viability. An argument about how it is related needs to be posted.

How is trading bushels of two kinds of wheat any different?

Or if this sight is seen as a non technical general crypto currency use site, then other technical questions off topic perhaps encryption on the crypto se and not here, software on regular se. Or for sake of asker, handle it softly here. Let it stay but just really let user know, if it involves some hard core economics or math, they might get better answer or quicker answer there, than here.

I for one will generally refuse to answer such questions, because i believe a basic person should be able to abstract real problems and then post them appropriately but is it still further to punish askers of such questiosn?

One of the off-topic reason is "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network". This seems like a relevant descriptor for these kinds of questions. Perhaps the description  can be expanded a bit.

According to the Help Center:

...and [the question] is not about …
programming
technique
investment
advice
politics or philosophy
a site or software recommendation

I'm not sure but I think these questions may be better suited for Money Stackexchange
